# How do I execute a function after completing first function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function `func1()`:

```
function func1() {
    do some stuff;
}
```

and another JavaScript function `func2()`.

```
function func2() {
    do some other stuff;
}
```

After completing `func1()`, how can I call `func2()`?

I know how to define callback handler for events like `onclick`,
but I don't know how to call `func2()` after `func1()` has been executed completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript is not multithreaded so I don't see what's the complication here. You should be able to do this:

```
function func1() {
    do some stuff;
    func2();
}
function func2() {
    do some other stuff;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Can you pl. see my comments to the answers above & maybe suggest a solution?  Thanks, Vineet

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
function func1() { 
    // Everything else
    func2();
}
```

or

```
func1();
func2();
```

or, if `func1` does something asynchronous, then you need some way to tell when it is finished. That will probably involve setting up an event handler, but the specifics depend very much on what the function actually does.

Comment: you got my prob right.  func1() does an async call to a server-side script, which generates html table content. func2() applies ".dataTable() plugin". When func2() is executed, the dataTable formatting/styling momentarily appears & again reverted back to plain html table. What maybe wrong in my methodology? ...Vineet

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method to what others have suggested (calling a global function at the end of the first function) is:

```
function f1(callback) {
    //do some stuff
    callback();
}

function f2() {
    //do some other stuff
}

f1(f2);
```

Comment: @ Josh, Thanks. I accepted your answer. Now the further problem is -- func1() executes a server-side script which generates html table content. func2() applies ".dataTable() plugin".  When func2() is executed, the dataTable formatting/styling momentarily appears & again reverted back to plain html table.  Any hint?  ..Vineet

Comment: solved it.  I converted those functions into JQuery and then executed the same from the server-side script itself.